# replace double qoute with inch PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-split

I have an variable `$query` which holds for example `5.6" display` or `5.6 " display` is there anyway to change it to `5.6 inch display` for both of the previous given examples? I tried using preg_split but I had no luck so far.

Comment: You want to remove the quotation marks?

Comment: Yes, and replace it with "inch"

Comment: `str_replace()` should work

Comment: Is the variable guaranteed to only have the double quotes after a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
str_replace('"', ' inch', $query);
```

To replace any quotation marks with " inch"

If you put in 5.6" it will output

```
5.6 inch
```

EDIT: If you want to remove double spaces of which would happen if you input

```
5.6 "
```

Then you should run this code after

```
preg_replace('/\s/', ' ', $query);
```

Comment: but he don't want to remove...

Comment: @steven wait, he's still reading the question :)

Comment: **Hint**. The solution is not necessarily a simple `str_replace`

Comment: @Enayet You're slowly getting there. Keep trying

Comment: Why don't you just provide your own answer? I've given a solution that will work but if you have a solution that works better then go ahead and share

Comment: It's a learning curve for you also. OP is looking to replace a double quote after a number (could include a white space before and after) followed by a string

Comment: Yeah I know that's why I'm eager to hear your solution. I'm not here to disagree I'm here to learn :)